# Equal height layout of 3 module content, best method?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In looking at this image you can see in an ideal world each box would have the same height of content in each box. However in the real world we can't control how many characters the client uses for a heading. Wondering thoughts on how to deal with a situation like this? Is it ok to just let it be as is?

[image]

Comment: You should decide what you want to implement, and ask here if you get stuck doing so. SO isn’t going to help you make design decisions, it’s a programming Q+A

Comment: Ok thanks I wanted to get suggestions or advice from real world but guess I'm in the wrong place

Comment: However, there is NO CSS method of equalising heights between elements that *do not share a parent*. Javascript would be required.

Comment: If take a look at the comments in SO and the other communities, they are limited to 600. You can use [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) to limit what is shown on a **single line** with 3 dots in the end (ellipsis) on a single line. For **multi-line** text you can set width/height to align the elements and add limit for the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

This will create an array of heights of an element by class, then find the tallest, and then make them all that height.

```
<script>
var headerHeights = [];
var mclength = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass").length;
for (i = 0; i < mclength; i++) {
    headerHeights[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[i].getBoundingClientRect().height;
}
var headerMaxHeight = Math.max(...headerHeights);
for (i = 0; i < mclength; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[i].style.height = headerMaxHeight+"px";
}
</script>
```

You will likely want to make this a function which replaces "myClass" with a function parameter so that you can call it for each class you add.  You will also want to add a listener for when a person resizes their window to rerun the function.

Comment: Can you explain max(...headerHeights)

Comment: The "..." is called a spread operator.   Math.max() is designed to accept values as a series of parameters, not an array.  IE: Math.max(1,2,3) is right, but Math.max([1,2,3]) does not work.  The spread operator allows you to pass an array as a series of parameters to a function.  Math.max.apply(null, headerHeights); is another option you may be more familiar with.  The Math.max() function just means returns the greatest value out of all the parameters you pass it.